# Creating a file using cygwin and hadoop

Tags: unix, hadoop, cygwin

I'm using this tutorial to setup a first hadoop project :

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/mapred_tutorial.html#Source+Code

I'm confused by this section :

```
Sample text-files as input:

$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls /usr/joe/wordcount/input/ 
/usr/joe/wordcount/input/file01 
/usr/joe/wordcount/input/file02 

$ bin/hadoop dfs -cat /usr/joe/wordcount/input/file01 
Hello World Bye World 

$ bin/hadoop dfs -cat /usr/joe/wordcount/input/file02 
Hello Hadoop Goodbye Hadoop
```

How do I create the files file01 and file02 ?

When I run above commands () I receive the error : "file does not exist /usr/joe/wordcount/input/file01"

Comment: Do you have the input files in this path? this command copy the input files from your filesystem to hadoop distributed file system

Answer (score 0):

You can either create the files using a file editor, on cygwin, either `vim` or `emacs`(not certain about that).

Or you can copy paste below to create the files.

```
echo "Hello World Bye World" >  /usr/joe/wordcount/input/file01
echo "Hello Hadoop Goodbye Hadoop" > /usr/joe/wordcount/input/file02
```

There are other, more baroque techniques to put simple data into files, but given your problem definition, this should work fine.

(One other possibility, .... Could these files be part of the test or tutorial installation and you have missed a step running the install? If once you create these files, and you hit a new error message, consider dbl-checking you steps to confirm all is installed correctly)

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

r u pointing to the same path??
Else create files from your local file system.Then use `copyFromLocal` command to put it in HDFS. Then cat the file path/filename. this works.

```
bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /path/to/file/in/localfilesys/file01 /usr/joe/wordcount/input
bin/hadoop fs -cat /usr/joe/wordcount/input/file01
```